# How to check array for contents based off another var, utilize alert window through if statement?

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, uibutton, uialertcontroller

I am currently working on a small Bingo app. I'm having a few issues with this, however.

First off, I have button that when clicked, change images showing that that piece is marked (intended to mark the numbers that have been called). I have an if statement as follows:

```
 if BOneButton.isSelected && IOneButton.isSelected && NOneButton.isSelected && GOneButton.isSelected && OOneButton.isSelected {

        winConditionLabel.text = "You win!"

        func createAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bingo!", message: "You win!", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again?", style: .default) { (action) in

                self.NewBoardAction(sender)
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            alert.addAction(action1)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }
```

I am having a few issues with this. First off, the Alert window will not come up. Have I done something incorrectly? (This is my first time attempting to use Alerts, so that's very likely.) Secondly, the label, which I have been using to test to make sure that the program gets through the if statement in the first place, only updates after deselecting the final button in the row. This is the main issue I'm trying to fix right now. And lastly, I'm having trouble checking the calledNumbers array (which consists of exactly that - all the numbers that have been called) to make sure that the numbers that have been selected have been called.

I originally had something like this:

```
if BOneButton.isSelected && IOneButton.isSelected && NOneButton.isSelected && GOneButton.isSelected && OOneButton.isSelected && calledNumbers.contains(Int(randomBOne.text)) && calledNumbers.contains(Int(randomIOne.text)) && calledNumbers.contains(Int(randomNOne.text)) && calledNumbers.contains(Int(randomGOne.text)) && calledNumbers.contains(Int(randomOOne.text)) {

// do stuff here

}
```

But this wouldn't work at all. Is there a better way to do this? I'd really appreciate any help at all!

Pertaining to the issue with checking the array. Here is the code for the first letter. The others do essentially the same thing:

```
@IBAction func newNumberAction(_ sender: Any) {


    // B NUMBERS

    let randomLetter = ["B", "I","N","G","O"]
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomLetter.count)))  // Gives random number from 0 - 4

    if (randomLetter[randomIndex]) == (randomLetter[0]) // if statement for each index/letter possibility {

        let randomBIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(listBNumbers.count))) // listBNumbers is the original array that randomizes a number from 1 - 15

        if randomBIndex < 1 // makes sure there are still B numbers remaining and if not runs the newNumberAction again {

            newNumberAction((Any).self)

        } else {
        let newBNumber = "\(listBNumbers[randomBIndex])" // creates unique variable for random BNumbers
        let combinedNumber = (randomLetter[0]) + newBNumber
        var calledBNumbers = [Int]() // creates array for called BNumbers
        calledBNumbers.append(Int(newBNumber)!) // adds called B Number into new array
        listBNumbers.remove(at: (Int(randomBIndex))) // removes B Number from bank of possible numbers that could be called, this should ensure that no number can be called twice

        calledNumbers += calledBNumbers // adds called B Numbers to new array that will be used later to verify BINGO

         newNumLabel.text = combinedNumber
        // this randomizes the number and combines it with 'B' then displays it in the label's text. This is used to display the next called Number.
        }
```

I know the append is working by checking a label that gives me the count of the variables in the calledNumbers array. Again, I apologize that I didn't provide enough information originally.

Comment: the alert won't appear because you have the function declared inside of the if statement. Create it outside of the if statement then call it inside the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your first problem the alert won't appear because you have the function declared inside of the if statement. Create it outside of the if statement then call it inside the if statement
2. Your second problem doesn't include enough context in the code for anyone to help you with. How would anyone other then yourself know what the *"final button in the row"* is?
3. Your last problem has the same issue as the second problem, *"I'm having trouble checking the calledNumbers array"*. There isn't an array in your question so how can anyone help you with identifying the problem?

This should fix your First problem:

```
if BOneButton.isSelected && IOneButton.isSelected && NOneButton.isSelected && GOneButton.isSelected && OOneButton.isSelected {

        winConditionLabel.text = "You win!"

        createAlert() // now that this inside of the if statment it will run
 }

// this should be declared outside of the if statement
func createAlert() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Bingo!", message: "You win!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        // your alert's code

 }
```

You added array information but there still isn't enough context. This is the best I could do based on what I ASSUME you wanted. Your code still isn't clear enough. You should've added all the arrays with foo info. For now I added an array `var listBNumbers = ["X", "Y", "Z"]` with `X,Y,Z`  as the `listBNumbers` values to use in your code since you didn't provide anything.

```
var listBNumbers = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

let randomLetter = ["B", "I","N","G","O"]

/*
// YOUR ORIGINAL CODE
let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomLetter.count))) 
*/

// 1. TEMPORARILY set this to 0 so that if statement below will run. Delete this and uncomment out your original code above when finished
let randomIndex = 0 

if randomLetter[randomIndex] == randomLetter[0] {

        /*
        // YOUR ORIGINAL CODE
        // randomIndex is of type INT there is no need to cast it as Int again in step 7B when your removing it from the listBNumbers array
        let randomBIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(listBNumbers.count)))
        */

        // 2. TEMPORARILY set this to 2 so that the else statement below will run. Delete this and uncomment out your original code above when finished 
        let randomBIndex = 2

        if randomBIndex < 1 {

            // I have no idea what this is
            newNumberAction((Any).self)

        } else {

            // 3. newBNumber is now: Z
            let newBNumber = "\(listBNumbers[randomBIndex])"
            print("newBNumber: \(newBNumber)")

            // 4. combinedNumber is now: BZ
            let combinedNumber = randomLetter[0] + newBNumber
            print("combinedNumber: \(combinedNumber)")

            // 5. THIS IS AN ARRAY of type INT it will not accept Strings
            var calledBNumbers = [Int]()

            // 6A. newBNumber is of type STRING not a type INT. This line below CRASHES because what your saying is calledBNumbers.append(Int(Z)!). How can you cast a Z to an Int?
            calledBNumbers.append(Int(newBNumber)!) // newBNumber contains the letter Z

            // 6B. THIS IS MY ASSUMPTION seems like you wan to use
            calledBNumbers.append(randomBIndex)
            print("calledBNumbers: \(calledBNumbers.description)")

            // 7A. check to see if the index your looking for is inside the listBNumbers array
            if listBNumbers.indices.contains(randomBIndex){

                // 7B. randomBIndex is ALREADY of type Int. Why are you casting it >>>Int(randomBIndex)
                listBNumbers.remove(at: randomBIndex)

                print("listBNumbers: \(listBNumbers.description)")
            }

            // 8. There is no context for me to even try and figure out what calledNumbers is so I can't give you any info about it
            calledNumbers += calledBNumbers

            // combinedNumber contains: BZ from the step 4 so that is what your newNumLabel.text will show
            newNumLabel.text = combinedNumber
            }
        }
```

Here's a way to clean up this code so it's more readable. You need to break all of that down into smaller functions so its more readable:

```
if areButtonsSelected() == true && doesCalledNumbersContainBingo() == true{
    // do stuff here
}

func areButtonsSelected() -> Bool {

    if BOneButton.isSelected && IOneButton.isSelected && NOneButton.isSelected && GOneButton.isSelected && OOneButton.isSelected{
        return true
    }

    return false
}

func doesCalledNumbersContainBingo() -> Bool {

    let b = Int(randomBOne.text)
    let i = Int(randomIOne.text)
    let n = Int(randomNOne.text)
    let g = Int(randomGOne.text)
    let o = Int(randomOOne.text)

    if calledNumbers.contains(b) && calledNumbers.contains(i) && calledNumbers.contains(n) && calledNumbers.contains(g) && calledNumbers.contains(o){
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: You're right. I apologize for not providing enough information. I managed to fix the issue with the alert thanks to you. I've also solved the second issue. As for the third, I am about to update my question with a better description.

Comment: I glanced it over. With this statement "if (randomLetter[randomIndex]) == (randomLetter[0])" your saying "if the index of the randomLetter with a generated index is equal to the first index of the randomLetter array" but you have a comment that says "// if statement for each index/letter possibility". There is only 1 possibility for this if statement to work. The only way it will run is if the constant randomIndex generates a 0. If it generates anything other then a 0 then your if statement won't run. Do you understand?

Comment: if "let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomLetter.count)))" generates any number other then 0 then "if (randomLetter[randomIndex]) == (randomLetter[0])" won't run. So basically if "let randomIndex = ... returns 1" then "if (randomLetter[1]) == (randomLetter[0])" this isn't true so it won't run. You have to remember randomLetter[randomIndex] // randomIndex contains a 1

Comment: Also, you have a comment that says "listBNumbers is the original array that randomizes a number from 1 - 15". If this is a normal array with 15 objects then the yes the count is 15 but it would randomize from 0 - 14 not 1 -15. Arrays start at index 0 not index 1. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107 Read the section: Accessing and Modifying an Array -"NOTE
The first item in the array has an index of 0, not 1. Arrays in Swift are always zero-indexed."

Comment: It was easier for me to just add comments above each line for the array part. Read the comments form 1 - 8 and use the print statements inside your actual project so you can see what getting printed out inside the console

Comment: I truly appreciate your help on this. You have definitely explained things to me in a clear way that helped me to understand them better. Again, thank you so much for your assistance. I finally managed to get everything working the way I needed it to, though, admittedly, it probably isn't the cleanest or most efficient way of doing so. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: np check the updated answer. I simplified the other thing you asked about. Good luck and Happy Coding! :)